# Does EASA require airliners to be fitted with autopilots?

Tags: airliner, easa-regulations, autopilot

For EASA OPS requirements, must an airline transport airplane be fitted with an autopilot system?

Comment: I'm an ATPL student in Eu and during my study I have read that for FWS (Flight warning System) It is a requirement for EASA OPS to have an ALTITUDE ALERTING SYSTEM for all turbjet aircraft and turbine powered ac weighing more than 5700kg or has more than 9 seats. But I have not found nothing about the requirements for A/P for aircraft.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed EASA requires "autopilot" but they don't state it directly like "every airliner flying in the European airspace must be autopilot equipped". They require it *indirectly*.

When I first read your post I immediately thought of RVSM. I recall talking to an ATCO (retired now) about automation on board, and he told me that without autopilot you cannot fly in RVSM airspace.

So I had a look in [skybrary concerning RVSM](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Reduced_Vertical_Separation_Minima_(RVSM)) and they did the dirty job for us. They mention all 3 EASA regulations  `IR-OPS SPA.RVSM.100 and SPA.RVSM.110`, `EU-OPS 1.241`, `EU-OPS 1.872` and they have quoted the interesting parts:

> Regulatory Requirements[...]
>
> An operator shall ensure that aeroplanes operated in RVSM airspace are equipped with:[...]
>
> **An automatic altitude control system**

Emphasis is mine.

There might be other regulations requiring other automatic flight components but I am not aware of them although a quick look in the documents reveals references to auto-land systems as well so these documents cover more than RVSM.

The summary is that EASA does not simply specify "you need autopilot if you fly an airliner" but they go into detail, of *what* they require and for *what* reason.

---

<sup>**Acronyms**</sup>

<sup>`RVSM` Reduced Vertical Separation Minima</sup>

<sup>`ATCO` Air Traffic Control Officer</sup>

Comment: This answer could be improved by expanding RVSM at least once.

Comment: @ErinAnne hope it's better now :)

Comment: Absolutely!  Though you left out EASA from your acronyms (kidding, kidding)